# How to find the total time I spent on my laptop in this year?

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, time

I am interested in knowing the total time I spend working on my laptop in 2016.

```
last reboot --since 2016-01-01 --until 2016-12-31 | grep -o '(.*)' | grep  -v '-'
```

gives me the total uptime of the laptop in this format:

```
(01:33) 
(04:40) 
(01:31) 
(1+06:41) 
(02:47) 
(00:30)
```

Now how do I add it up?

Comment: can you tell me the meaning of (1+06:41) ?

Comment: @kashish 1 day, 6 hours, 41 minutes

Comment: The thing is that `wtmp` logs (which is what you see in output of `last` command) are set to rotate monthly (in `/etc/logrotate.conf`), meaning that after certain time period , the oldest log gets deleted. In other words,  whatever you're trying to do with `last` , it wont be accurate

Comment: @Serg I've disabled logrotate for wtmp. It's been more than an year since I did that, and the file size is currently 3.7M. So I don't see any reason why it should be rotated monthly. ;)

Comment: @daltonfury42  If it is disabled it won't rotate. Most users don't do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an awk  + awk version:

```
last ... | awk '/reboot/{print $NF}' |
    awk -F '[(+:)]' '
        {
            d += $(NF - 3); h += $(NF - 2); m += $(NF - 1)
        }
        END {
            carry = m / 60; h += carry;
            carry = h / 24; d += carry;
            printf "%d days, %d hours, %d minutes\n", d, h % 24, m % 60
        }'
```

`last`'s last column is in the format `(<days>+hours:minutes)`, where `days+` is dropped if the period is less than 1 day.

Here, the first `awk` command outputs the last column, the duration of interest, for `reboot` entries.

For the second `awk` command:

1. `FS` is `[(+:)]`, i.e., parentheses *or* `+` *or* `:`. So, `(h:m)` is split to , `h`, `m` and  (first and last fields empty), and `(d+h:m)` is split to  , `d`, `h`, `m` and  (again, first and last fields empty).
2. Then we take the second-last field for minutes, third-last for hours and fourth-last for days. The fourth-last field will be the first, empty, field if days is not present. So, we'll be simply adding `0` in this case.
3. Then we bump up the hours and days by if minutes and hours are above 60 and 24 respectively. Note that awk does floating point division, so `h` and `d` may now have fractional parts.
4. Then we print the numbers as integers (`%d`), so any fractional part is ignored.

Answer (score 8):

Trying with bash script and extending your command.
I use `dateutils` to add up the time duration.

Hence to use this script one needs the `dateutils` package available through `apt`.  ( `sudo apt install dateutils` )

This script takes into account the current uptime (present session) also, hence more accurate. Seconds are not counted. Lowest unit reported is minute.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Total uptime reported.
temp=$(last reboot --since 2016-01-01 --until 2016-12-31 | grep -o '(.*)' | grep  -v '-' | sed 's/(\([0-9]\{1,\}\)+\([0-9]\{1,\}\):\([0-9]\{1,\}\))/\1d\2h\3m/g ;s/(\([0-9]\{1,\}\):\([0-9]\{1,\}\))/\1h\2m/g'  )
curr=$( cat /proc/uptime |  perl -ne '/(\d*)/ ; printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n",int($1/86400),int(($1%86400)/3600),int(($1%3600)/60)'  )
echo "Total run time (days:hours:minutes)"
curr="2015-01-01T"$curr
org="2015-01-01T00:00:00"
new=$(dateutils.dadd $curr $temp )
dateutils.ddiff $org $new -f "%dd %Hh %Mm"
```

- First the uptimes from last reboot is listed and formatted to extract the day, hours, minutes and second information. This is then saved in `temp`.
- A reference fake date is set called org=`2015-01-01` to which current uptime is added.
- Then all cumulative uptimes are added to the variable `new`
- The duration between `org` and the net uptime `new` is found by difference.

---

**Output:**

```
vayu@helix:$ ./uptime_record.sh
Total run time (days:hours:minutes)
57d 20h 36m
```

---

The following script is for the uptime in exactly **one year from the day the script is run**.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Total uptime reported since exactly 1 year (from the time script is run).
now="$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')" ;
last_y=$(dateutils.dadd $now -1y)
temp=$(last reboot --since "$last_y" --until "$now" | grep -o '(.*)' | grep  -v '-' | sed 's/(\([0-9]\{1,\}\)+\([0-9]\{1,\}\):\([0-9]\{1,\}\))/\1d\2h\3m/g ;s/(\([0-9]\{1,\}\):\([0-9]\{1,\}\))/\1h\2m/g'  )
curr=$( cat /proc/uptime |  perl -ne '/(\d*)/ ; printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n",int($1/86400),int(($1%86400)/3600),int(($1%3600)/60)'  )
echo "Total run time in one year (days:hours:minutes)"
curr="1980-01-01T"$curr
org="1980-01-01T00:00:00"
new=$(dateutils.dadd $curr $temp )
dateutils.ddiff $org $new -f "%dd %Hh %Mm"
```

Comment: Somehow I like bash scripts, but I know here that more elegant answers are possible.

Comment: According to your script, I spend 2258days, 01hours, 15minutes online last year.

Comment: Error fixed. Code compacted to 8 lines.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a python implementation of what I want, but I am sure there is an elegant way to do it with bash:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.run("last reboot --since 2016-01-01 --until 2016-12-31 | grep -o '(.*)' | grep  -v '-'| sed -e 's/(//g; s/)//g; s/+/:/g'", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
mins_total = 0

for line in output.stdout.split('\n')[:-1]:
    try:
        (hrs, mins) = [int(k) for k in line.split(':')]
        days = 0
    except:
        (days, hrs, mins) = [int(k) for k in line.split(':')]
    mins_total += (days*24 + hrs)*60 + mins

print("Hours: " + str(mins_total/60))
print("Days: " + str(mins_total/60/24))
```

Comment: _“I am sure there is an elegant way to do it with bash”_ IMHO Python is a better choice. Bash is good for file manipulations, not for calculations.

Answer (score 0):

As of May 22nd 2023, UBUNTU and all *NIX has a command called "ac".
If not available , add 'acct' package.

```
Inspiron-ubnt:~$ ac
total       67.71
```

Installing:

```
Inspiron-ubnt:~$ sudo apt install acct
```